# jaxb contain CDATA with ]]> inside CDATA

Tags: java, jaxb

I m having a problem when i unmarshal an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <id>01O5</id>
  <message codage="UUENCODE"><![CDATA[begin 644 encoder.bufM,C8W.SQ3S4[0S$Q,30Q,#8Q,#$P,3]]>CU#/U_SEY[]@]MY84)8[<J?IF^>8'6_Z(__N'7C+]\^.HO?U'SAZ]^P)APS"JMC>!>LIXX
]]>
   </message>
</test>
```

as you can see inside message i have in the midlle a ]]> that means CDATA end! but end of cdata is later in the xml, so unmarshall not working with jaxb

How can i tell jaxb to find CDATA end at the end of the tag and not at the middle of the xml?

thanks for help

Comment: Can you please post the errors that you are getting

Comment: Is that xml you are generating yourself? As that xml is invalid in the first place. JAXB is used to work on valid xml, not on invalid XML. However is generating that xml shall generate correct xml. Forget jaxb, you can't even parse that xml using any parser.

If you are looking for help on how to generate correct cdata tag then can ask

Comment: no this is not a xml that i generate myself, and you answer right, xml is not correct, i m going to tell the person who send me this to change the xml ;)